# One portion of the JavaScript code in an if statement runs, while the rest of the code in the same block doesn't execute. What am I missing here?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So, I have a web paged with a `position:fixed` header element, comprised of a container surrounding the header elements - a logo, navigation and a button/hyperlink. By default, the objects are arranged life this:

```
[<div class="header-left">][<div class="header-nav">][<div class="header-right">]
```

What I want to do is; when the browser viewport is resized (shrunk specfically) I'd like for these elements to be replaced by a 'collapsed menu' element, for usage with mobile. Something like this:

```
[<div class="header-left">][<div class="collapsed">]
```

I've tried to achieve this by calculating offsets of these elements relative to the parent element (`<div class="header-container">`) using their respective `position().left` values. I figured by recalculating the distance between the `header-nav` and `header-right` elements every time the window was re-sized, when the distance finally reaches 0 (or whatever offset I choose) I could just change these elements' to `display:none`.

This logic is contained in the following variable declarations and `if` statement:

```
if (intersect == undefined) intersect = $(".header-nav").outerWidth(true) + parseInt($(".header-nav").position().left, 10);
    distance = parseInt($(".header-right").position().left, 10) - intersect;

if (distance <= 10) {
    if (showAlert == true) alert("distance definitely less than 10");
    showAlert = false;
    $(".header-right").css( {"display" : "none"} );
    $(".header-nav").css( {"display" : "none"} );
    $(".collapsed").css( {"display" : "inline-block"} );
}
```

Strangely enough the `alert()` gets called as soon as the distance reaches 0, but the header elements don't collapse immediately - the viewport has to be shrunk even further. I really don't understand what's causing this behaviour.

Anyway, here's all of the relevant code. Thanks very much for any time you might spend giving me a hand with this one.

```js
//index.js    
//document.ready function wrapper.
//Event listener on resize and orientation (for mobile) events
//In order to determine whether or not the header menus should be collapsed
$(document).ready(function() {

    //checkHeader function : called every time the viewport is resized

    checkHeader($(window).width());

    $(window).on("resize", function() {
        checkHeader($(window).width());
    });
    $(window).on("orientationchange", function() {
        checkHeader($(window).width());
    });
});



var intersect; //distance from left of screen/header to right of header-nav element
var distance; //distance between intersect and header-right's left side 

//checkHeader : Contains code for checking whether or not a header element
//should be collapsed or uncollapsed.

function checkHeader(width) {

    //Checks to see if the distance between the header-right element and
    //header-nav elements is <= 10 (10 being an arbritary offset). If it
    //is, these elements should collapse and the collapsed menu should display
    //THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM IS.


    if (intersect == undefined) intersect = $(".header-nav").outerWidth(true) + parseInt($(".header-nav").position().left, 10);
    distance = parseInt($(".header-right").position().left, 10) - intersect;

    if (distance <= 10) {
        console.log("distance definitely less than 10, but have menu elements collapsed?");
        $(".header-right").css({
            "display": "none"
        });
        $(".header-nav").css({
            "display": "none"
        });
        $(".collapsed").css({
            "display": "inline-block"
        });
    }

    if ($(window).width() >= intersect) {
        $(".header-right").css({
            "display": "initial"
        });
        $(".header-nav").css({
            "display": "initial"
        });
        $(".collapsed").css({
            "display": "none"
        });
    }


    //DEBUG OUTPUT 
    $(".debug").html(
        "DEBUG <br><br>" +
        "Current screen width: " + width + "<br><br>" +
        "Intersect: " + intersect + "<br>" +
        "Distance between right and nav: " + distance + "<br><br>" +
        "Header-right left relative to header: " + parseInt($(".header-right").position().left, 10) + "<br><br>" +
        "Is menu collapsed?: " + isCollapsed + "<br><br>"
    );

    return;
}
```

```css
/*index.css*/


body {
 position: relative;
 z-index: 0;
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
 font-size: 0.6em; 
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

header {
 background-color: rgba(9, 135, 136, 0.9);
 border-bottom: rgba(5, 99, 99, 1) 1px solid;
 min-width: 100%;
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 1; 
 color: white;
 white-space: nowrap;
 font-size: 1.4em;
 overflow: hidden;  
}

.header-container {
 position: relative;
}

.header-left {
 display: inline-block;
 float: left;
 padding: 10px
}

.header-nav {
 position: relative;
 top: 3px;
 display: inline-block;
 float: left; 
 padding: 10px;
}

.header-right {
 position: relative;
 top: 3px;
 display: inline-block;
 float: right;
 padding: 10px;
}

.header-nav > a {
 margin: 0 5px 0 5px; 
 text-decoration: none; 
 transition: color 300ms ease;
 color: white;
}

.header-nav > a:hover {
 color: rgba(246, 22, 96, 1);
}

.header-right > a { 
 transition: color 300ms ease;
 color: rgba(5, 85, 85, 1);
 text-decoration: none;
}

.contact:hover {
 color: white;
}

.order-tracking {
 padding: 5px;
 border: rgba(5, 85, 85, 1) 3px solid;
 border-radius: 10px; 
 background-color: white;
}

.order-tracking:hover {  
 transition: background-color 500ms ease;
 background-color: rgba(230, 230, 230, 1);
}

.collapsed {
 position: relative;
 top: 6px;
 display: none;
 float: right;
 padding: 0 3px 0 3px;
 margin: 0 20px 0 0; 
    transition: background-color 100ms ease,
       border 500ms ease;
 border: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 2px solid;
 border-radius: 7px;
}

.collapsed:hover {
 background-color: rgba(2, 99, 99, 1); 
 border: white 2px solid;
 border-radius: 7px;
}

.carousel {
 display: none;
 padding-top: 48px;
}

.clear {
 clear: both;
}
```

```html
 <!--index.html-->


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
  <title> Omitted </title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; 'charset=UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">  
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/public/css/global.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/public/css/index.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/public/js/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/public/js/header.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/public/js/index.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <header>
   <div class="header-container">
    <div class="header-left">   
     <a href="/"><img src="/public/img/logo.png" height="24" width="135"></a>
    </div>    
    <div class="header-nav">
     <a href="/public/workstations.html">Workstations</a>
     <a href="/public/servers.html">Servers &amp; HPC</a>
     <a href="/public/network-storage.html">Network Storage</a>
     <a href="/public/personal-computers.html">Personal Computers</a>
    </div>    
    <div class="collapsed">
     <a href="/public/order-tracking.html"><img src="/public/img/collapsed.png" height="28" width="36"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="header-right" >   
     <a class="contact" href="/public/index.html#contact">Contact Us</a>    
     <a href="/public/order-tracking.html" class="order-tracking">Order Tracking</a>
    </div>
   </div>
  </header>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <div class="carousel">   
   <div class="left arrow"></div>
   <img src="/public/img/offer-header.jpg" alt="Offer Header" >
   <div class="right arrow"></div>
  </div>
  <a name="contact" href="tel:omitted"></a>
  <div class="debug"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What if `distance` is less than 11 but `window.width()` is bigger than `intersect`? That next `if` statement will set the style right back.

Comment: Also, don;t debug with `alert`. Use `console.log`. It doesn't block your code and is easy to see the history.

Comment: @Pointy The thing is, I tried preventing that by assigning a a variable `isCollapsed = false` by default, then morphing that value based on the result of the initial `if` statement - but the variable never changed it's state. It's like only select parts of the code in the `if` block runs.

Comment: @DarkFalcon You'd think I'd know better. Thanks dude :')

Comment: @JonathanBrooks have you put a `console.log()` in that second `if` statement just to make sure it's not firing?

Comment: This code is extremely hard to read. You need to embrace the use of braces (`{` and `}`) with `if` statements and run this through jslint to clean it up.

Comment: @Pointy The second statement is indeed firing. As mentioned before though, if I introduce a variable `isCollapsed = false` by default as another comparitor to the first if statement, it doesn't change state when I ask it to in code...

Comment: You should add that code to the question; I don't really understand what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without having an easy way to experiment with your code, it's hard to troubleshoot this for you, but I would strongly suspect what's happening here is that both `distance <= 10` and `$(window).width() >= intersect` are `true`, so the first `if` executes, and then the second one executes right after it, restoring everything back to normal.

If that is indeed the problem, you can avoid this by using an `else`:

```
if (distance <= 10) {
    // ...
}
else if ($(window).width() >= intersect) {
    // ...
}
```

***However***, I think you are [going about this the wrong way](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) anyway. The recommended way to do adaptive layouts is to use [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries):

```js
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .header-right, .header-nav {
        display: none;
    }

    .collapsed {
        display: inline-block;
    }
}
```

This will allow you to apply specific styles to your page when the browser window is less than a certain width.

This will allow you to replace that large chunk of JavaScript with this small chunk of CSS and then you can just focus on tweaking the layout.

Comment: Oh my god. That's literally the most amazing thing ever. All that javascript was completely unecessary!! Thank you so much.